# Проверка заполненности таблицы в JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Есть таблица.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td /> <td />
        <td /> <td /> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td /> <td />
        <td /> <td /> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Когда по ячейке таблицы кликают мышью, туда записывается текст. Как используя JQuery определить, что все ячейки таблицы содержат текст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то так:

```
var empty = 0;
$('td').each(function(){if(!this.innerHTML)empty=1;});
```